SharePoint communication site banner title not changing
I have built a communication site in SharePoint and for some reason I now can’t change the title on my banner. Or, more to the point, I can edit and save the change but it always reverts back to the previous when the page is refreshed after republishing. I’ve edited this loads of times already so not sure why it doesn’t work now.  I’ve also tried deleting the web part entirely and adding a new one but to no avail. Any help appreciated.

We had a similar issue with site pages and banners and eventually found a workaround/fix. On the site, navigate to site contents, click site pages, find the page, click radio button of page and in details section, you can edit the title in the title field from here.
Hope this helps.

